# Read multiple files from the directory into a file, newline separated

Tags: script, cmd.exe

My script is:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set LF=^


rem ** The two empty lines are necessary
set "content="

for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /s D:\v\*.*') do (
  set "content=!content!%%x!LF!"
  echo. >>

)
echo(!content!>a.txt
endlocal
```

I read all the file names from directory `D:\` and write them to `a.txt`.  The output looks like

```
D:\v\a.csvD:\v\b.txtD:\v\c.xml
```

I need the output to be

```
D:\v\a.csv 
D:\v\b.txt 
D:\v\c.xml
```

How can I get a newline after each filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I get a newline after each filename?

Write them out in the `for` instead of building up an output line.

Use the following (much simplified) batch file.

**test.cmd:**

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /s D:\v\*.*') do (
  echo %%x>>a.txt
)
endlocal
```

I don't have a drive D: so the following test was run on drive F:

**Example Output:**

```
F:\test>dir f:\v
 Volume in drive F is Expansion
 Volume Serial Number is 3656-BB63

 Directory of f:\v

03/08/2016  08:40    <DIR>          .
03/08/2016  08:40    <DIR>          ..
02/08/2016  20:43                 0 a.csv
02/08/2016  20:43                 0 b.txt
02/08/2016  20:43                 0 c.xml
               3 File(s)              0 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,772,975,259,648 bytes free

F:\test>test

F:\test>type a.txt
F:\v\a.csv
F:\v\b.txt
F:\v\c.xml

F:\test>
```

Comment: Thankyou. But when i tried to run the above code its storing only the last filename. In output file a.txt I am able to see only one filename i.e:D:\v\c.xml.Could you please help me to store all the values in a.txt.

Comment: I've tested it here and it works fine.

Comment: Could you please share the complete code which you have tested.

Comment: @user3051956 Erm it is in the answer ...

Comment: Thankyou verymuch for your help.It's working from my end.But i need some help from you..My other requirement is to add timestamp to all the files which are stored in a.txt. Suppose in a.txt we have files like a.csv,b.txt,c.xml, for this we need output like a_(timestamp).csv,b_(timestamp).txt,c_(timestamp).xml.

Comment: @user3051956 Please ask a new question (referencing this one for context). Be sure to specify exactly what you mean by `timestamp` (where it comes from, what format to use, etc).