# Add time stamp to the files present in .txt files

Tags: batch-file

I have a batch script (based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1107957/337631)):

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /s D:\v\*.*') do (
 echo %%x>>C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\a.txt
)
move /y C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\a.txt C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\b.txt
```

The output of the batch code is

```
D:\v\a.csv
D:\v\b.txt
D:\v\c.xml
```

Now my requirement is to add timestamp i.e: `%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%` to output files.

Example: My output file is D:\v\a.csv but now it should be

```
D:\v\a_%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.csv
D:\v\b_%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.txt
D:\v\c%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.xml
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### My requirement is to add a timestamp

Use the following batch file.

```
@echo off
set datetime=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('dir /b /s D:\v\*.*') do (
  echo %%~dpnx_%datetime%%%~xx>>C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\a.txt
)
move /y C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\a.txt C:\Users\TechMadmin\Desktop\scripts\b.txt
```

Notes:

- `%%~dpnx` is the full filename, including the drive and path, but excluding the extension (example `D:\v\a`).
- `_` is the underscore character.
- `%datetime%` is the value of the date time string
- `%%~xx` is the file extension (example `.csv`).
- `>>` is the redirection operator.
- Not fully tested.

  You are using a locale dependent function to get the date components (which doesn't match my system date format)

  - A simplified example works as expected.

If you want a locale independent solution for the date and time components see my answer [Print datetime in Windows cmd](https://superuser.com/a/1045459/337631) for the code required.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.

Comment: Can you please tell me what this does:   %%~dpnx_%datetime%%%~xx>> in the above code.

Comment: @user3051956 Answer updated. See also the second further reading link ...

Comment: The above script is running successfully at my end,I noticed one situation where the script fails.
Suppose if I receive same files(a.txt,a.txt) on same day and after adding timestamp to it ...the two files looks like
a_08042016_095244.txt
a_08042016_095244.txt

These two files are send to ETL tool as inputs where it fails saying duplicates files exits.
Can you please tell us how to differentiate this two files in order to process.
Regards,
Venu.Ch

Comment: @user3051956 Hmm. How you get two files called `a.txt` in the same directory in the first place? That shouldn't be possible. I would suggest using the file creation time as a timestamp. See my answer [Get creation time of file in milliseconds](https://superuser.com/a/937401) for how to do that.

Comment: Is there any way to append date time string to files in different way.Output of the code. D:\v\a_0805201616112099.pdf
D:\v\b_0805201616112099.txt
D:\v\c_0805201616112099.xml.Here for all the files same time is added,but it should take differently like there should be some milliseconds change to the files.Please help here.

Comment: Posted new question based on my requirement.